# Expression of personality at the workplace

Tags: team

What are some guidelines/ good philosophies in expressing your personality at work?

I am a gregarious guy and my line of work is software development. I laugh louder than the average guy at jokes. I speak honestly about how I feel about most issues technical or non-technical. At the same time, I try to soften the blow when I say something that could be considered as abrasive or pointing but needs to be said. I also show a back-bone and stand up to superiors from other teams who try to push their weight around.

If you have been around people like me in the workplace, have you enjoyed working with them? In what way would you like people like me to be different?

Comment: Hi Jay, this is a good post, but it's not really what we're looking for on the Workplace SE. Instead, we look for questions that are about a real, actual problem you're facing, not the beginning of a discussion. Since you're bringing this here, I assume maybe something happened to you at your workplace. Perhaps there's a problem that you're trying to solve that you're not telling us about? I'm sorry, I have to close this for now, since it doesn't fit our Q&A format, but I invite you and others to [edit], describe a problem, and focus on something solvable we can reopen. Hope this helps!

Comment: As an aside, it may help to take a look at our [faq] and [about] pages, which tell you more about what our site is about, why we're here, and what problem this site solves that others don't. You can also ask for help with edits and rewording your posts in [chat]. Good luck! :)